# Safety of software installation from source code

Tags: software-installation, security

Sometimes I'm told to compile a source code in order to use a recent version of a software.
How do I know if it's safe to do that?

Normally I install software via the "Ubuntu Software Center".
How do I know if a certain source code that is located in a certain website is truly the source code of a "known" software that is available in "Ubuntu Software Center" ?

Comment: You could always audit the source code yourself...

Comment: You don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the package's page on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) and click on the "homepage" link. This will take you to the package's homepage, which should direct you to its official source.

> [image: screenshot of homepage]

Comment: This hardly addresses the safety aspect of the question.

Comment: I meant to imply it. If you build from the official sources, then it's just as safe as the package.